# Compute the stratified value of n+nn+nnn

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I want to Write a console application that take a *integer number* from client and check if this *number* can be *stratified*, i.e. can be represented as

```
 number = d + dd + ddd + ... + dd...ddd
```

where `d` is some *digit*. For instance

```
 36 = 3 + 33
861 = 7 + 77 + 777
335 - can't be represent in d + dd + ddd way
```

So far I have only been able to figure out how to allow the user to input an integer.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input integer");
            //ask user to input integer
            String n = Console.ReadLine();
            string nn = Console.ReadLine();
            string nnn = Console.ReadLine();
            //allows user to input integer

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to take a digit from client and if this digit can be stratified following equation(digit = n+nn+nnn+nnnn+...), return true else return false Suppose client enter 36= 3+33 >> return true.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. What's stopping you from writing that equation in C# exactly? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you tried to break the requirements down into steps and research / try each smaller part? That usually makes things easier. What's your actual _problem_? (This site is not a free write-my-code service, but we will _help_ you if you show some attempt.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is checking different digits to find the solution:

```
// IsStratifified input n
for(int d = 1; d <= 9; d++) {
    var s = d;
    var c = d; 
    while(s < n){
        c = 10 * c + d; // generates dd, ddd, ...
        s += c;
    }
    if (s == n)
        return d;

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your number has d digits.

Find a(d) and a(d-1): a(n) = (10^n-1)*(10/81) - n/9

Choose the larger of these two that is smaller than the input number, which will usually be a(d).

If it divides your number evenly then your number is stratified.

Note that a(n) is 1 + 11 + 111 + ... + 11...11 (ending with n 1s).

e.g. 36: a(2) = 12. 36/12 = 3.

e.g. 861: a(3) = 123. 861/123 = 7.

e.g. 335: 335/123 = appx 2.72.

This is O(1).

a(n) formula courtesy of [Henry Bottomley & OEIS](https://oeis.org/A014824)